# AWS CDK codepipeline action for updating lambda with new build

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I have a pipeline i'm currently trying to set up via AWS CDK. It's hosted on github and i want to have it update the lambda with a new build every time there's a code update.

Currently, i have this as my stack.

```js
    // the buildspec will be in the repo
    const project = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, "CahmCodeBuild", {
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename("buildspec.yml"),
      environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_6_0,
      },
    });

    // Create the new pipeline

    const deployPipeline = new pipeline.Pipeline(
      this,
      "LambdaPipeline",
      {
        pipelineName: "lambda-pipeline-name",
        crossAccountKeys: false,
        artifactBucket,
      }
    );

    // define the artifact

    const sourceOutput = new pipeline.Artifact();

    // github connection setup

    const sourceAction = new actions.GitHubSourceAction({
      actionName: "GitHub_Source",
      owner: "my-name",
      repo: "my-repo",
      oauthToken: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager("my_secret"),
      output: sourceOutput,
      branch: "master", // default: 'master'
    });

    // codebuild setup

    const buildAction = new actions.CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: "CodeBuild",
      project,
      input: sourceOutput,
    });

    // putting everything together!

    deployPipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Source",
      actions: [sourceAction],
    });

    deployPipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "BuildDeploy",
      actions: [buildAction],
    });
```

It's at this point i'm actually a little stuck. As far as my experience goes, to update the lambda i just need to upload a new zip of the build. I've checked over the docs and maybe i've just missed it but i cannot find an action that will help me do this.

Is there a function i'm missing? I could manually do it through the codes buildspec.yml using aws-cli but i feel that's just not the right thing to do here.

Edit:

I found [this recent(ish) article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/save-time-reduce-errors-automating-lambda-code-updates/) that went the aws-cli route. Is this still the correct way to do this?